# Webcam/mic access SWF

Tags: flash, webcam

I am not a flash developer so I don't have the toolkits to download example scripts to build a SWF that would let me access the users webcam and mic.

What I am looking for is something like flowplayer but for accessing the webcam and mic rather than playing video.

All I need is a configuration parameter or two that sets the quality, size and where to send the RTMP stream (I believe this is what most flash webcam scripts stream?)

I've googled for hours and all I can find is action script examples.

Comment: Are you looking to gain access to the users webcam and microphone? Or simple play back a stream from another user?

Comment: I want to gain access to the users webcam and mic and stream that data to a url. I believe that stream should be rtmp, but I may be barking up the wrong tree here.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem.  Eventually I gave up on finding an off the shelf widget.  If you're avoiding Flash because of the cost and you're not afraid to roll your sleeves up a bit, the following worked for me.

I used [Haxe](http://haxe.org), a free multi-platform compiler which can compile to swf, and followed examples from [HaxeVideo](http://code.google.com/p/haxevideo/).

You can completely ignore the server component and just compile the code in the Samples folder.  Main.hx has the RTMP values you'll want to change.

If needed, you can build in flashvars and a JavaScript wrapper for the component.